# Understanding paperjs point.length

Tags: paperjs

My knowledge on js is none. i'm trying to convert a script to python. but have got stuck on this snippet:

```js
var length = circumfrence * 1.14 / points;
var segment = blob.segments[i];
var nextIndex = (i == points - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
var nextSegment = blob.segments[nextIndex];

var toNext = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
if (toNext.length > length) {
    toNext.length = length;
```

normally when finding the distance i use:

```js
var dx = segment.point.x - nextSegment.point.x
var dy = segment.point.y - nextSegment.point.y
var toNext = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
```

how is `toNext.length = length;` being calculated? whats happening to the two points in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

[`Point.length`](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#length)

> The length of the vector that is represented by this point’s coordinates. Each point can be interpreted as a vector that points from the origin (x = 0, y = 0) to the point’s location. Setting the length changes the location but keeps the vector’s angle.

If you obtained your point by subtracting two points `B - A`, it represents the vector which goes from `A` to `B`. A point can always be seen as a vector which goes from the origin to its position.

You might need `Point.getDistance(point[, squared])` instead:

[`Point.getDistance(point[, squared])`](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#getdistance-point)

> Returns the distance between the point and another point.